# Monotone function, inverse image of an interval

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Could you tell me how to prove that if $f$ is monotone,the inverse image of an interval is an interval?

Does it suffice to say that $f^{-1}(a,b) = (f^{-1} (a), f^{-1}(b))$ ?

Comment: You probably mean a monotone continuous function. I'm guessing this is homework - is this a first course in Analysis? If it is, then you want to provide some more detail: for instance, $I$ is an interval iff for every $a,b \in I, a < b, (a,b) \subseteq I$

Comment: @Pedro: Continuity is actually not necessary.

Comment: @CameronBuie True, you're absolutely right. Thanks.

Comment: If you could prove that $f^{-1}((a,b))=(f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}b)$, it would follow that the inverse image of every open set is open, i.e. $f$ is continuous. But there are of course monotone functions which are not continuous. The problem with your formula is that $f^{-1}(a)$ or $f^{-1}(b)$ may not even exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "interval," this needn't be true in general. For example, if $f(x)=e^x$, then the preimage of any interval $I\subseteq(-\infty,0]$ will be the empty set.

For the sake of making the result true (and dealing with degenerate cases), let us call $I\subseteq\Bbb R$ an interval iff for any $a,b\in I$ with $a<b$ we have $(a,b)\subseteq I$. This definition includes the empty set, singletons, non-degenerate bounded intervals, rays, and $\Bbb R$ itself.

Suppose $B=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)\in I\}$ for some interval $I$, where $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is monotone. Suppose we have two points $a,b\in B$ with $a<b$, and take any $y\in (a,b)$. It suffices to show that $y\in B$. Indeed, since $f(a),f(b)\in I$, and since $f(y)$ lies between (or perhaps equal to one of) $f(a),f(b)$ by monotonicity of $f$, then we have $f(y)\in I$ since $I$ is an interval, whence $y\in B$.

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference. I would consider degenerate intervals to be intervals, thereby negating your 'counterexample' since $(a,a)=\varnothing$. If there is a standard convention not to assume this, I'm unaware of it.

Comment: Fair enough, Clayton.

Comment: @CameronBuie  In my definition, the interval for the range of f is taken to be the smallest interval containing the image of f, i.e. f(I), so the counter-example you give isn't related to what I'm considering.

Comment: @Matt: Are you considering a similar problem, then? (By the way, you don't have to tag me, since this is my answer.)

Comment: @CameronBuie  I'm trying to understand your approach (with the set B you defined). So now we are considering some interval I to be in the range of f (not the domain). Are we requiring all points in I to have a pre-image in the domain of the function? or ex, the map of an interval, J, under a piecewise monotonic function with a single jump discontinuity will be two disjoint intervals (let's suppose they're finite for now) and they lie in an interval. So if we let I be the interval containing the two disjoint intervals and B would equal J, right?

Comment: To answer your last question, I guess the prototypical problem I am considering is the one I cited earlier: the map of an interval which is a piecewise monotonic function with a single jump discontinuity. I appreciate your patience and your help: I don't mean to sound simple, I just want to understand things completely.

Comment: @Matt: It seems like you have the right idea, but we do not require that $I$ be in the range of $f,$ only in the codomain. Let me see if I can illustrate further by way of example. Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & x<0\\x+2 & x\ge 0.\end{cases}$$ This is readily monotonic, and has range $(-\infty,0)\cup[2,\infty).$ Then if we had let $I=[0,1],$ we would have $B=\emptyset,$ a degenerate interval that vacuously satisfies the definition I gave for interval. If we had $I=[0,2],$ then $B=\{0\},$ which again vacuously satisfies the definition I gave.

Comment: I am trying to understand the motivation for your definition. In my defn, I am requiring I to be the smallest interval *containing* the range. My motivation for doing this, is it will allow eliminate any ambiguity as to whether a function is surjective or not and it will also allow me to make statements like "given we define the codomain of f as the smallest interval containing its range, we can say if f is injective, then f is continuous". With your definition, however, you are looking at the points not in the range of f. What is the motivation for doing this?

Comment: @Matt: So you're trying to prove that if a real-valued monotone function $f:\Bbb R\to I$ is *surjective* (where $I$ is the smallest real interval containing the range of $f$), then $f$ is continuous? The motivation for my definition is just to make the result true, by calling a subset of $\Bbb R$ an interval if and only if it is [(path-)connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). It's true that it suffices to consider connected subsets of the range of $f,$ rather than intervals of the codomain $\Bbb R,$ but it makes it a bit trickier to do the proof.

Comment: In our class, we know 3 things about functions so far: continuity, bijectivity, and monotonicity. My interest is in the relationship between these 3 properties. I know continuity and either of the other 2 implies the remaining condition. But when you get to the question of whether bijective and monotonicity imply continuity, the answer depends on what functions qualify as bijective, since, as your example points out, surjective can depend on the codomain. I was interested in a "well defined" codomain for injective maps that would remove this subjectivity. But perhaps this is not a useful idea.

Comment: @Matt: We can certainly always restrict the codomain so that injective implies bijective. However, monotonicity plus injectivity need not imply continuity, since (for example) considering the $f$ which I defined in a comment above, we see that $f$ is a monotone bijection $\Bbb R\to(-\infty,0)\cup[2,\infty),$ but that $f$ is not continuous at $x=0.$

Comment: Yes, I think I am probably trying to be a bit too restrictive and rule out the possibility of jump discontinuities. Again, I apologize for my probably simple minded question: I am new to analysis and just trying to get a feel for things and my classmates don't seem all too interested in such details. Thank you again!

Comment: @Matt: You are very welcome! I hope I was able to clear things up for you, at least somewhat. Keep that curiosity!