# Suppose $f \colon \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ and that $f$ is increasing. Show that $f$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $f \colon \Bbb R \rightarrow  \Bbb R $  and that $f$ is increasing. ($x$ < $x'$ $\implies $ $f(x)$ < $f(x')$). Show that $f$ is measurable.

I am a self taught person and just started reading about this. I was wondering what this proof might look like. Can you please show it to me so I can understand what this is saying?

Does the interval $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ work here? Is there other way to show this? 
This is the Lebesgue Measure on $  \ \Bbb R $.

I still do not get this. These hints are very vague since I just started reading about this. I only know a little from reading. If I see this proof I will be able to solve other problems like this. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure how you would prove this. I am looking at some other problems too. This would be the start. Can someone please show how to do this so I can try solving the other problems. I would like to learn this topic.

Comment: Is someone there who can help me with this?

Comment: Why all the anxiety and the rush?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The sets $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ are intervals for all $a$.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail please? I just started reading about it. Does this mean that there is some preimage. How do we go from here.

Comment: What does  this mean?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: @9959 $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is the preimage of $(a,\infty)$. If you can show this preimage is a measurable set for all $a$, you are one. Since intervals are measurable, it suffices to show $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is an interval, which means that for all $a<c$, $a,c\in f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ and $a<b<c$, you have $b\in f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ That shouldn't be too hard to show.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The preimage of any interval (including the empty set, singletons, rays, the whole real line) under an increasing function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ [is an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353095/monotone-function-inverse-image-of-an-interval/353111#353111) (again, including the aforementioned cases).

Comment: Can you explain more in detail with proof? Is it possible you can show how do you start it? Is the interval f^-1(a, infinity) ok?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: Yes, that means that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is an interval (in the general sense) for all real $a$. All such intervals are measurable, which you should be able to show if you haven't seen it proved already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is enough to check that $f^{-1}(a,\infty) \in \Sigma$ as it (usually) is the definition of measurability for a real valued function to be measurable. Where $\Sigma$ is your sigma algebra which I guess is either the Borel-sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ or the Lebesgue sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ since you haven't specified anything else. Now we know that all open sets are contained in the sigma algebra so pick some $x \in f^{-1}(a,\infty) = A $. We must show that there is an open ball containing $x$ that is contained in $A$. Clearly $ x > \inf f^{-1}(a,\infty)$. Hence we can find an epsilon such that $ x-\epsilon > inf \; f^{-1}(a,\infty)$. Now just take the ball $B(x,\epsilon) = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \; | \; |x-y| < \epsilon \} = (x-\epsilon, x + \epsilon) $. Now clearly every element in this set gets mapped to the interval $(a, \infty)$ by definition of epsilon and the fact that $f$ is an increasing function so $A = f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is an open set hence it is contained in $\sigma$ thus $f$ is measurable.

Comment: It is the Lebesgue sigma algebra on R.

Comment: Ok. Then it contains all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ so the proof above holds. Did you understand it?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Now I am able to solve other problems just like this. I just tried another problem like this and was able to do it. Thanks for making it clear.