# Prove $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone iff $f^{-1}[x,y]$ is an interval for each $[x,y]\subset\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotone if and only if $f^{-1}([x,y])$ is an interval for each $[x,y]\subset\mathbb{R}$

**My attempt:**
Suppose that $f$ is monotonically increasing then for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, if $x\leq y$ then $f(x)\leq f(y)$

Let $f^{-1}:[f(x),f(y)]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a local inverse of $f$. As $f$ is monotonically increasing then $f^{-1}$ is monotonically increasing.

Moreover, $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and $f^{-1}(f(y))=y$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: In general, your local inverse will only be a right inverse, i.e., $f(f^{-1}(z))=z$. In fact, $f$ need not even be injective.

Comment: What if $f$ is a constant?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f$ is *not* monoton. Then there exist $a,b,c$ with $a<b<c$ and
$$f(a)<f(b)>f(c)\quad\text{or}\quad f(a)>f(b)<f(c). $$
Let
$$I:=f^{-1}([\min\{f(a),f(c)\}, \max\{f(a),f(c)\}). $$
Clearly, $a\in I$ and $c\in I$, whereas $b\notin I$ - contradicting the given condition that $I$ is an interval.

We conclude that $f$ is monoton.

Comment: (+1) And @FutureReader for the converse, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/353111