# Let $g\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous increasing function, then $g^{-1}(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ is an open interval.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous increasing function on $[a,b]$.
We consider an open interval contained in $[\alpha,\beta]$, say $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)\subset [\alpha,\beta]$. Since $g$ is a continuous mapping , $g^{-1}((\alpha_0,\beta_0))$ is an open set contained in $[a,b]$.

I don't understand the following statement:

> The monotonicity of $g$ implies that the open set $g^{-1}((\alpha_0,\beta_0))$ is an open interval, rather than a union of two or more disjoint open intervals.

Comment: Can you say anything about the preimage?

Comment: It is clear that the preimage is open because $g$ is continuous. However it might not be connected, consider $f(x)=x^2$ and as interval $(1,2)$, for example.

Comment: @Matthias you forgot the monotonicity hypothesis. In order for $f$ to be increasing, you need to restrict it to $I:=[0,+\infty)$, and then it becomes a homeomorphism from $I$ to itself.

Comment: @AnneBauvalThanks!But, I don't understand how this answer can help me. The point I need has not been proven.

Comment: @Anne Bauval, my intention was to illustrate why the monoticity assumption is necessary by giving an example what might go wrong in the more general case. Maybe if OP analyzes what goes wrong in the counterexample that I gave he can see which role the monoticity contion plays.

Comment: @NatMath It has been proven, but in another answer, which I linked later in comment to that one. So that actually, the true duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353095)

Answer (score 0):

As $g\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then there is a critical result in Real Analysis, which says that there exists an inverse function $f: J \to \mathbb{R}$, where $g([a,b]) = J$ such that $f$ is increasing and continuous on $J$. That implies $g^{-1}$ is continuous, so $g^{-1}(\alpha_{0},\beta_{0})$ is also a connected set, so it can't be the union of two disjoint open intervals. And you know how a connected interval looks in $[a,b]$.

$\textbf{Another approach:}$
Now if $g\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and strictly increasing function, it is injective. Now let $J = g([a,b])$. Now, as $g$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact, $J$ is also compact and $g : [a,b] \to J$ is a bijective map from a compact space to a Hausdroff space, so $g$ is a homomorphism. Rest is simple

Comment: The continuity is actually useless, and the result holds even is $f$ is only "increasing" in the broad sense, i.e. non-decreasing, i.e. $x\le y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/353111).